# Binding multiple progress bars

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, progress-bar

Referring to screenshot below, I have the following view and viewmodel setup to represent progress bar download. When I add more than 1 downloads to this collection of downloads, it seems that download 1 will overwrite download 2's Progress() public property.

Example below is download 1 is downloading 1MB it will finish first and compared with download 2 downloading 5MB. 
When download 1 finish, download 2 (hello2 example below) progress bar just stop there but the bytes are still being downloaded at background until 5MB is reached.

How can I change the code to ensure download 1 does not interfere with download 2's progress bar UI. I've tried modifying Progress() to private but then both progress bar UI is not shown

**View**

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding GameDownloads}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GameName}" />
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding StatusText}" />

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**DownloadAppViewModel**

```
Public Class DownloadAppViewModel
Inherits ViewModelBase

Private ReadOnly WC As WebClient
Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal URL As String, ByVal FileName As String)
    _gameName = Name
    WC = New WebClient
    AddHandler WC.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompleted
    AddHandler WC.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgressChanged
    WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(URL), FileName)
End Sub
Private Sub DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

End Sub
Private Sub DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As [Object], ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    If _totalSize = 0 Then
        _totalSize = e.TotalBytesToReceive
    End If
    DownloadedSize = e.BytesReceived
End Sub

Private _gameName As String

Public Property GameName() As String
    Get
        Return _gameName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gameName = value
        Me.OnPropertyChanged("GameName")
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property StatusText() As String
    Get
        If _downloadedSize < _totalSize Then
            Return String.Format("Downloading {0} MB of {1} MB", _downloadedSize, _totalSize)
        End If
        Return "Download completed"
    End Get
End Property

Private _totalSize As Long
Private Property TotalSize() As Long
    Get
        Return _totalSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        _totalSize = value
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalSize")
        OnPropertyChanged("Progress")
        OnPropertyChanged("StatusText")
    End Set
End Property

Private _downloadedSize As Long
Private Property DownloadedSize() As Long
    Get
        Return _downloadedSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        _downloadedSize = value
        OnPropertyChanged("DownloadedSize")
        OnPropertyChanged("Progress")
        OnPropertyChanged("StatusText")
    End Set
End Property


Public ReadOnly Property Progress() As Double
    Get
        If _totalSize <> 0 Then
            Return 100.0 * _downloadedSize / _totalSize
        Else
            Return 0.0
        End If

    End Get

End Property

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Do you continuously hitting DownloadedSize() setter even after download1 finish?

Comment: hmm yes based on StatusText() to update my text.. is this causing download1 to overwrite download2's UI progress?